# How do I increase the line spacing in Aptana Studio 3's editor?

Tags: aptana

Is it possible to increase the space between lines in Aptana Studio 3?  If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah Andrew is right. It is not possible yet using Aptana Preferences.

I use a manual trick, though it is not something technical.
I do it on my Aptana Studio 3.5.0 installed on Linux Ubuntu 12.04. Not sure it will trick on other OS.

I just copy any UTF-8 hindi test, just paste it on the top of my PHP file.
This code is not some technical thing it is just for an example. It has nothing to do with coding or Aptana preferences.

Example :
`<?php // हिन्दी ?>`

If I just paste it for a while and then remove it, it will keep the increased line height until I close the file.

[image]

Comment: Also, you can also choose to use increased High Line fonts.Check out this -> https://github.com/Salauyou/Consolas-High-Line

Answer (score 1):

No, it seems that it's [not possible yet](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3912).